# Knowing Redux in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My reducer is like below

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'Hello': {
            console.log('hello');
        }
        default: return state
    }
}
```

I would like to separate `action` from reducer. I would like to import it into reducer from another file. How can I do that ?

**Another Question**

I have a `submit` button like below.

```
<div onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</div>
```

I am calling below function when submit button clicked.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    this.props.dispatch( { type: 'Hello' } );
  }
```

What is `type` here ? Why should I use it ? What is it doing inside reducer/actions ?

Comment: "I would like to separate `action` from reducer. I would like to import it into reducer from another file. " `action` is an argument. How do you imagine you would import it from another file. Please clarify. Also please avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko, Is it possible to import ?

Comment: Is it possible to import an argument? Well, no. I'm not sure what you mean. Please come up with some sort of a pseudo-javascript you'd like to have.

Answer (score 0):

An **action type** is a string that simply describes the type of an action. They're commonly stored as constants or collected in enumerations to help reduce typos.

```
export const Actions = {

  GET_USER_DETAILS_NAME: 'NAME',
  GET_USER_DETAILS_AGE: 'AGE',
  GET_USER_DETAILS_LOCATION: 'LOCATION',

  // more...
};
```

An action to fetch the user named Bob might look something like this

```
{
   type: 'NAME',
   payload: 'Bob'
}
```

**Reducers** specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store.

```
function getUserDetails(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NAME:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
    case AGE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
    case LOCATION:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```